# File upload event in the form of creating a new post on Facebook

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I created a Chrome extension with Angular and I want this extension to automatically create a new post when I enter the Facebook site.
But the problem I have is that when I upload the photos of that post in the input file with javascript, the files property is filled, but because the rest of the events are not done automatically, Facebook does not display them correctly, And the required field error is executed.

my code :

```
const inputElement = document.querySelector('input[accept="image/*,image/heif,image/heic"]') as HTMLInputElement;

    console.log(inputElement.files);

    const imageUrl = 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ssrtest-cebd9.appspot.com/o/temp_fb_test%2F360_image_number_21.jpg?alt=media&';

    fetch(imageUrl)
        .then(response => response.blob())
        .then(blob => {
            const file = new File([blob], 'myimage.jpg', { type: blob.type });

            const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();
            dataTransfer.items.add(file);

            const fileList = dataTransfer.files;

            inputElement.files = fileList;
            const changeEvent = new Event('change');
            const inputEvent = new Event('input');
            inputElement.dispatchEvent(changeEvent);
            inputElement.dispatchEvent(inputEvent);
        });
```

[I want it to be exactly like when I manually upload a photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCg3H.png)

I was able to solve this problem like this :

```
fetch(imageUrl)
        .then(response => response.blob())
        .then(blob => {
            
            const file = new File([blob], 'myimage.jpg', { type: blob.type });
            const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();
            dataTransfer.items.add(file);
            const fileList = dataTransfer.files;
            inputElement.files = fileList;

            const eventNames = ['change', 'input', 'blur', 'focus'];
            eventNames.forEach(eventName => {
                const event = new Event(eventName, { bubbles: true });
                inputElement.dispatchEvent(event);
            });

        });
```